# Android MediaPlayer 2k video E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-22)

Tags: android, видео, videoview

У меня в приложении есть android.widget.VideoView для воспроизведения видео, внутри которого используется MediaPlayer.

```
    VideoView video = findViewById(R.id.videoviewclient);
    video.setVideoPath(videourl);
    video.requestFocus();
    video.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> mp.start());
```

Я использую этот плеер для воспроизведения видео с онлайн камер. В разрешении 1080p у меня все отлично работает на большинстве телефонов. Но после установки некоторых камер с разршением 2k видео уже не открывается на многих телефонах, в плеере вываливается ошибка "E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-22)" (на камерах с 1080p все прекрасно работает). Что сделать, чтобы 2k видео нормально воспроизводилось? Может быть есть возможность использовать аппаратное ускорение?

Я понимаю, что разрешение экрана на этих устройствах хуже, чем качество видео. Но все равно, можно ли что-то сделать на клиенте (не на сервере), чтобы это видео хоть как-то воспроизводилось?

Comment: банально не хватает мощности процессора

Comment: 2k видео не работает, к примеру, на моем Nexus 7 2-го поколения. С процессором Snapdragon S4 Pro (APQ8064) 4 ядра по 1.5 ГГц, плюс граф. ускоритель Adreno 320. Далеко не факт, что в этом случае проблема именно в мощности процессора, хотя в других случаях это не исключено